# Access DB PDO not working in Windows Server x64 edition

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, xampp, windows-server-2008

Guys I am really stuck up here with this Access DB. I made a php application for a company, the record exporting to MS access in the web application is giving me headache.

I installed Xampp 1.8.1x32 and MS office 2010 32bit professional in their Windows 2008 64 bit version server, everything is working fine! I enabled extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll in the php.ini and I tried to export data from mysql to accdb file using php PDO, but it's not inserting data into the accdb file.

I even tried adding a system DSN to the accdb file in both ODBC 64bit and ODBC 32bit by installing "Access Database Engine x64" and "Access Database Engine x32", but still out of luck. The same mysql to accdb data exporting is working fine in my win7 x64 and ms office 2010 x32 even without installing access database engine and without setting DSN!

Kindly let me know whether there is some other way out to insert data into accdb using PDO in Win 2008x64 server edition. Should I install any special access database edition in win 2008, or should I enable something to make it work?

Sorry for this lengthy and twisted post :p I didn't find solution anywhere else in the internet. Kindly help!

Update: There is no PDO or php errors displayed. just it's not working!

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What do they say? Are there errors? Permissions issues?

Comment: Which log should I check? And no, there is no PDO or php errors displayed. just it's not working! The folder and accdb is writable.

Comment: The webserver logs would be the best place to start. Otherwise, I'd start off with some debugging, and write some new code to test what's going on, dumping `ErrorInfo()` at every stage. Can your code connect to the server? Can it connect to the right database? Can it SELECT from the table? Can it UPDATE? Can it INSERT? There's presumably an issue in configuration between your dev environment and the live one, and that sort of thing will help you track it down.

Comment: where can i find webserver logs? yeah the db connectivity is working fine. there is no problem with it. the problem is with accdb file only!

Comment: I've got no idea where the webserver logs are - you'll have to go poking through the configuration to find it. And have you tried the rest of the suggestions? Write a small piece of code that connects and runs a SELECT statement - does that work?

Comment: Some versions of Apache - depending on your setup write error to the Windows Application Event Log by using the Event Viewer, e.g. Start - Settings - Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problems. I was able to read and display records but INSERT had no effect, no error was thrown either. The thing is, I kept trying to execute an SQL statement with the values already filled out. Once I tried the prepare and execute statements with actual parameters it did work. I have no idea why it behaves this way but it seems like you can't directly execute INSERT statements?

Btw I previously tried 'prepare - execute' with no arguments as well ( as the data was filled out in the query already ). Glad it only took me 3 hours of trial and error! :(